# Refinement Token for starts-with or prefix search

Tags: enterprise-search, display-template, refiner

I am trying to create a custom refiner based on the **path** managed property. After selecting it should show items in a directory so I have to use a prefix search with the property **path**.

```
var refiner = { "Path": ["ǂǂ" + asc2hex(directoryPath + '*')] };
ctx.ClientControl.updateRefiners(refiner, 'or', false, null);
```

Apparently this leads to zero results. When I leave out the * it only shows the directory.

Any pointers?

**Update 1 (8/6/2014 11:22):**

It partially works with

```
refiner = { "Path": ['starts-with("' + directoryPath + '")'] };
```

But that does only return 1 result - not not the elements in that directory. Anyone knows why?

Comment: So it is only showing items in sub-directories right now? If so, you could substring `directoryPath` to remove the last char (that probably is a `/`?)

Comment: It does show only the directory. But removing the trailing slash and adding a wildcard works!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
directoryPath = directoryPath.substring(0, directoryPath.length -1) + '*'
refiner = { "Path": ['starts-with("' + directoryPath + '")'] };
```

It could be a trailing `/` that stops it from including the current site

Comment: Thats a workaround for now - thanks for that. Its not 100% tho, imagine two folders with the name folder1 and folder11 ;)

Comment: Yeah there is still culprits with this approach. I don't think the `Path` attribute was meant to filter on a lower level than site, in which case removing the trailing `/` would not be necessary